# Managing UFT scripts in bitbucket by integrating to ALM?

Tags: git, alm

We have a requirement to kick start the UFT code from ALM by importing the latest update from bit bucket.We are using hp alm 12.55 and UFT 14.03.
interested to know if there any plug in or any other way to manage efficiently?

Comment: We are developing Bumblebee (https://www.agiletestware.com/bumblebee) - a product which allows you to run your UFT tests stored in bitbucket (so no need to upload them into ALM). Please check out the documentation: https://www.agiletestware.com/docs/bumblebee-docs/en/latest/ci-integration/jenkins/#-running-alm-tests-inside-jenkins

Comment: Thank You .I will check and revert back to you.